# Recorrer una matriz de objetos en C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Soy nuevo en C# y .NET. Quisiera saber como recorro un objeto que estoy creando.

```
public ActionResult<Person> Get(int id)
    {
        var pipe = new searchClient();
        var data = new[] {
            new Person { id=1, Name="Ana", edad="24" },
            new Person { id=2, Name="Joseph", edad="20" }
        };
        var looking = pipe.obtenerCliente(id, data);

        return Ok(
            looking
        );
    }

public class searchClient
{

    public Object obtenerCliente(int id, Array data)
    {
           foreach(var d in data) {
              Console.WriteLine(d); // Cuando recorro la matriz, me sale el contexto de los objetos
           }
        return data;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string edad { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando recorro la matriz con el foreach, en consola me regresa el contexto del objeto de Person, no se como seguir recorriendo eso

Comment: Seguir recorriendo que cosa? ahi ya estas recorriendo el array... que es lo que tratas de conseguir?

Comment: Me regresa el contexto del objeto Person, pero no puedo obtener las propiedades. Quiero conseguir las propiedades de New Person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El hecho de que declaras los parámetros de la rutina con un tipo que no tiene información sobre el tipo de elementos, como `Array`, que hace que sea necesario aplicar moldes de tipo si quieres llegar a los miembros de cada objeto en el arreglo y el código es, en mi opinión, más propenso a errores, pues nos saltamos las validaciones que el compilador hace por nosotros si usamos tipos estrictos.

Manteniendo la firma de la rutina, tienes que declarar el tipo de variable del elemento del iterador como `Persona`:

```
foreach(Persona p in data) {
  Console.Writeln(p.Name);
}
```

O puedes dejar el tipado implícito y aplicar el molde directamente a d:

```
foreach(var d in data) {
  Console.Writeln(((Person) d).Name);
}
```

Esto no evita que se escriba código que le pase a esta rutina un arreglo con elementos de tipo `Car` y no `Person`, pues hemos despojado al compilador de la posibilidad de verificar el tipo de elemento.

Si cambias la firma, puedes recibir un arreglo de personas, lo cual simplifica las cosas y nos mantiene del lado seguro con las validaciones del compilador:

```
public Person obtenerCliente(int id, IList<Person> data) {
  foreach(Person p in data) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    if (p.id == id)
      return p;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Dado que ahora hay un tipo definido para los elementos de `data`, incluso el tipado implícito funcionaría:

```
public Person obtenerCliente(int id, IList<Person> data) {
  foreach(var p in data) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    if (p.id == id)
      return p;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: var no es tipado dinamico para nada. el compilador ya sabe que d es de tipo persona. var solo es azucar para no especificar el tipo. en realidad, en su metodo, alcanzaba con hacer d.Name... y le iba a devolver el nombre. Le devuelve la firma del objeto porque quiere imprimir directamente d, que es un objeto, y no tiene sobrecargado el metodo ToString.

Comment: @gbianchi tienes toda la razón en que no es tipado dinámico, sino implícito. Estaba, sin duda, espeso en ese momento, agradezco la aclaración, edité la respuesta para corregir mi mala explicación y enfoque. Gracias por el comentario. Un saludo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te pasa aca, es que cuando haces esto:

```
Console.WriteLine(d); // Cuando recorro la matriz, me sale el contexto de los de los objetos
```

Le estas diciendo a C# que imprima ese objeto. Como ese objeto hereda de object, por mas que vos le hayas puesto propiedades, no sabe como se debe imprimir.

Esto es porque el [metodo ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0) como bien dice la documentacion, imprime el nombre completo del objeto, que no es lo que vos queres, porque vos queres que imprima su contenido.

Para eso, aca, tenes dos opciones:

- escribir en el for cada variable:

  ```
   Console.WriteLine(d.name);
   Console.WriteLine(d.edad);
   Console.WriteLine(d.id);
  ```
- Sobreescribir el metodo ToString en tu clase, para que sepa como imprimir

  En este caso, dentro de tu clase Person, debes hacer:

  ```
   public override string ToString()
   {
     return name + " " + edad + id.ToString();
   }
  ```

De esa forma, cuando hagas:

```
Console.WriteLine(d)
```

va a imprimir el nombre la edad y el id...

---

Notas:

- Si vas a usar nombres en ingles, que sean todos en ingles (name, edad?), si no, todos en español
- Usar var cuando sabes el tipo de variable, aunque no esta mal, no es recomendable. [Var](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) le deja el trabajo al compilador, y este lo hace bien, pero si alguien ve tu codigo, tiene que andar adivinando de que tipo es. Usualmente se usa, con objetos anonimos y devoluciones de objetos complejas.  Si sabes que d es de tipo Person, no hagas `var d in data`, mejor hace `person d in data`
- la edad, suele ser un int.. no esta mal que sea un string, pero es un numero, siempre es un numero ;)...